# How to add filter to joined table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have this query which works as expected. It returns all rows, and joins two tables if possible.

Now, I want to uncomment the last two lines so that the joined tables only includes those records where IsPrimary = 1.  (If IsPrimary = 0, then I do not want to do the join and the columns should be null.)

When I uncomment those lines, then it stops returning all the rows from the Organization table.

How do I modify this query to work as expected?

```
Select top (Select ts.MaxRecords
 from TableSettings ts
 where ts.TableName = 'Organization') 
            O.*,
            L.Name,
            ISNULL(C.FirstName, '') + ' ' + IsNull(C.LastName, '') as FullName

        FROM [dbo].[Organization] O 
        left join Location l on l.OrganizationId = o.Id
        left join Contact c on C.LocationId = l.Id

        WHERE
        O.TenantId = @tenantId and
        (@id IS NULL OR O.Id  = @Id) AND
        (@name IS NULL OR O.Name LIKE '%' + trim(@Name) + '%') AND
        (@organizationTypeId IS NULL OR O.OrganizationTypeId = @organizationTypeId) 
        --and l.IsPrimary = 1 and
        --C.IsPrimary = 1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Move your criteria from the where clause to the join.

With inner join they're equivalent, but for left join it's the difference between a null result vs no result.

Comment: Thank you, didn't realize that could be done. It works.

Answer (score 0):

```
 Select top (Select ts.MaxRecords
 from TableSettings ts
 where ts.TableName = 'Organization') 
        O.*,
        L.Name,
        ISNULL(C.FirstName, '') + ' ' + IsNull(C.LastName, '') as FullName

    FROM [dbo].[Organization] O 
    left join Location l on l.OrganizationId = o.Id and l.IsPrimary = 1
    left join Contact c on C.LocationId = l.Id and C.IsPrimary = 1

    WHERE
    O.TenantId = @tenantId and
    (@id IS NULL OR O.Id  = @Id) AND
    (@name IS NULL OR O.Name LIKE '%' + trim(@Name) + '%') AND
    (@organizationTypeId IS NULL OR O.OrganizationTypeId = @organizationTypeId)
```